# Howto get UISlider to respond to tap events on the track above and below the thumb slider

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have a 284 pixel wide UISlider with a range of 0-25. The user needs to select a value to 1 decimal place (say 12.3), which is possible with care by rolling your finger, but is fiddly and tends to change value as you lift your finger.

I am trying to arrange it so that you can inch the slider up or down by 0.1 intervals by tapping on the slider rail above or below the thumb. I'm sure it's possible, but as this is my first xcode project I'm struggling. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's not exactly relevant with your question, but you should checkout OBSlider: http://oleb.net/blog/2011/01/obslider-a-uislider-subclass-with-variable-scrubbing-speed/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options come to mind:

1. Create invisible buttons and place them to receive these clicks
2. Subclass UISlider and intercept the touchesBegan, etc methods.  Determine if you want to respond to the hit based on its location, or call the super's function.  You may need to expand the frame to include where you're touching.

I'm not sure that creating a non standard (especially invisible!) implementation is a great idea, however - I'd recommend you add visible buttons for fine-tuning.  A simple up-arrow / down arrow to the side might help.  Also consider if a UISlider is what you want at all, given that it doesn't work well enough for you.

Comment: Wow that was quick! I hear what you say about the non-standard implementation, but I felt the behavior was logical albeit invisible. If I subclass UISlider can I selectively intercept taps only? I am struggling to get my head around the touch event response chain.

Comment: If you subclass UISlider, only the functions you implement will intercept the calls - everything else will pass down to the super class (UISlider).  So if you only implement touchesBegan, you'll only intercept touch down events.  See UIResponder documentation for the touches functions you might want to implement.  Again, if you don't want to intercept the call (for touches directly on the slider, for example), call [super touchesBegan:...] and let the UISlider superclass handle it.

Answer (score 4):

I think a better solution is just to subclass UISlider, and to re-implement

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

by returning YES when the touch event is inside the slider bounds.

Answer (score 2):

A long-standing problem with the iPhone OS' UISlider control is that you can't make it taller. More specifically, you can make it look taller by specifying taller images for its thumb and track, but the touch area stays as a tiny 23px tall.

What you need to do is subclass UISlider, and override pointInside in your class:

```
// How many extra touchable pixels you want above and below the 23px slider
#define SIZE_EXTENSION_Y 10

- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds = CGRectInset(bounds, 0, SIZE_EXTENSION_Y);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(bounds, point);
}
```

In Interface Builder, set the slider to use your new UISlider subclass, and you now have a slider with a 43px touchable height.

Comment: You can't make the slider taller in the nib editor (Interface Builder), but you can make it taller in code.

Comment: Works for me: I just set the frame with the proper height in code with the rest of the code which customized the slider with my custom images. I had a problem where touches were not working below a certain point but I found that it was due to the UIView that I had wrapping the UISlider which did not have the proper height. It was cutting off the customized slider. By fixing the height of the containing UIView I was able to get the touch/height issue resolved and I removed the custom MySlider class I was trying to use to fix the issue.

Comment: Doesn't work unless combined with - (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: The size extension needs to be NEGATIVE otherwise the inset actually DECREASES the touchable pixels:

#define SIZE_EXTENSION_Y -10

(tested with iOS 5 & iOS 6)

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Builder you cannot set the height of UISlider because it is fixed. But in your code where you set the values for the thumb image and the track images you can set the frame height as you see below. This will open up the area which is sensitive to touches.

```
CGRect sliderFrame = self.mySlider.frame;
sliderFrame.size.height = 42.0;
[self.mySlider setFrame:sliderFrame];
```

Comment: Good tip, thanks Brennan. Some users find the sliders insensitive (dry fingers I think) and enlarging the touch area has definitely helped. As it happens my problem was making the slider respond to touches.

Comment: Couldn't get this solution to work for me, although it seemed pretty easy.